# Load data local infile is not working in Ubuntu 14.4 LTS

Tags: python, mysql, load

`path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'pythonscript', 'ftp', fname)
        print(path)
        print ("-------------------load starts for "+tbname+"---------------------------------------------\n")
        query = """load data local infile"""+' '+path+' '+"""into table"""+' '+tbname+' '+"""fields terminated by"""+' '+"'|'"+' '+"""lines terminated by"""+' '+"'"+lt+"'"+' '+"""ignore 1 lines;"""
        cur.execute(query)`

Its working in my local windows system.

In the above code "**fname**": Filename and "**path**" : file path

am using **mysql.connector.connect** for DB connection after i run the load statement getting below error, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_to_mysql.py", line 73, in <module>
    cur.execute("""load data local infile"""+' '+path+' '+"""into table"""+' '+tbname+' '+"""fields terminated by"""+' '+"'|'"+' '+"""lines terminated by"""+' '+"'"+lt+"'"+' '+"""ignore 1 lines"""+";")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/home/ubuntu/pythonscript/ftp/INV_COST_FEED_GARBJ_20180417_00.txt into table ftp' at line 1
ubuntu@ip-X-X-X-XXX:~/pythonscript/ftp$ nano load_to_mysql.py`

Comment: hi sharath, even i am facing the same issues. Can anybody help me here...

Comment: Hi Suraj, have tried setting **local_infile=True** in connection, did you tried the same?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the quotes around the filepath

syntax to use near '/home/ubuntu/pythonscript/ftp/INV_COST_FEED_GARBJ_20180417_00.txt into table ftp' at line 1

[See docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

> The file name must be given as a literal string. On Windows, specify
>   backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes.
>   The character_set_filesystem system variable controls the
>   interpretation of the file name.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your time. If i use quotes in the query getting below error   **mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: File '/home/ubuntu/pythonscript/ftp/INV_COST_FEED_GARBJ_20180417_00.txt' could not be read**

Comment: 'local' infile means the file is on your client machine. Drop 'local' if the filepath  is on your database server.

Comment: as suggested removed **'local'** in code, getting error like **mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: File '/home/ubuntu/pythonscript/ftp/INV_COST_FEED_GARBJ_20180417_00.txt' could not be read**
} hence am using correct connection like     **conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='XXX',user='XXX',password='XXX',db='finrecon',port='XXXX'**

Comment: Two things to check. Do have the FILE privilege? Do you get a dir path if you query SELECT @@secure_file_priv; , if so, put the file there.

Comment: given permission like **chmod -R 766 /home/ubuntu/pythonscript/ftp/**   >>Other one ***Select @@secure_file_priv;*** can't able to run tried in Ubuntu ***mysql -u(username) -p(password)*** no luck

Comment: No, FILE privilege relates to the mysql user account e.g.  SELECT `file_priv` from mysql.user where user = 'your_user'; It should say 'Y'. Don't know why you can't select @@secure_file_priv - it's a system variable there are no restrictions on querying it. Instead you could try: show variables like 'secure_file_priv';

Comment: for user 'XXXX' i have File_priv 'N', so am trying to give permission for that user like ***grant all privileges on dbname.* to 'XXX'@'%' with grant option*** but File_priv still has 'N'

Comment: Last one. The FILE privilege is global, you can't grant it for a single db. You need to use GRANT FILE ON *.* to 'XXX'@'%'

Comment: it worked finally.. Thanks for warm reply.. In local file we are using file with extension '.txt' but in server it case sensitive need to use '.TXT', we should include local in load statement.